# Return list of interface type

Tags: c#, class, oop, inheritance, interface

I have three clasess that inherit from the same interface:

```
Apple:Resource
Banana:Resource
Orange:Resource
```

I another class I have lists with the type op each one:

```
private List<Apple> apples = new List<Banana>();
private List<Banana> bananas = new List<Empleado>();
private List<Orange> oranges = new List<Orange>();
```

Now I want a method that can return any of those lists, lets say something like this:

```
public List<Resource> getListOf(string resource)
{
    switch (resource)
    {
        case "apple": 
            return apples;
            break;
        case "bananas":
        return bananas;
            break;
        case "oranges":
        return oranges;
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("wrong fruit");
            break;
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<Fruits.Apple>`' to
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<Fruits.Resource>`'

I thought it would work the same manner as I can do:

```
foreach (Resource r in Fruitlist) {
    r.Meth();
}
```

Comment: You could use "private List<Interface> x = new List<ActualType>();" for your members and then return them as that in your function. And then test and cast them when you need their real types (with is and as).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The feature that makes the code break by its absence is called *generic type covariance*. C# does support [variance in generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx), but only in interfaces (not concrete classes).

The `foreach` snippet works because it treats `Fruitlist` as an `IEnumerable<Fruit>`, and since that's a generic interface with an `out` (covariant) type parameter the compiler can view it as an `IEnumerable<Resource>`.

If it's acceptable for `getListOf` to return an `IEnumerable<Resource>` then changing the function signature will make the code compile. Otherwise the compiler would not be able to guarantee type safety, because you could write this code:

```
List<Resource> apples = this.getListOf("apple");
apples.Add(new Orange()); // adding a Resource to a List<Resource>, right?
```

Another option would be to return a non-generic type, in which case type safety would be again lost and the compiler would introduce runtime checks to make sure that you don't mix apples with oranges (but at least the code would work if it's well-behaved).

Comment: Thanks Jon, first of all it worked, so great :) but I'm still not sure about the example, how does having IEnumerable instead of the interface avouces me adding a wrong type to a list?

Comment: @Trufa: The point is that `IEnumerable<T>` does not allow you to modify the collection, that's why it's able to be covariant. If it had any method that accepted a `T` as a parameter (as opposed to using it as a return type) then it would not be allowed to have an `out` type parameter.